# How to disable Apple SMC or Reorder dev/input/js*

Tags: drivers, input, gamepad

I bought a generic usb controller and installed the package `joystick` and `jstest-gtk` to calibrate/set the mapping. In the `jstest-gtk` gui there is `applesmc` (this is an old macbook) as `dev/input/js0` and it's using the gyroscope as a joystick. Is there a way to either disable this or reorder these so I can have the gamepad as the default?

Thanks

Comment: Read my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/545214/circumventing-macbook-pros-motion-sensor-using-dev-input-js0-as-a-joystick